# How to fix a .mov file in hex editor from Photo Booth crash on OS X?

Tags: macos, audio, video, ffmpeg, quicktime

I was recording a ~4GB video using Photo Booth on OS X. The program terminated for some reason (unsure of whether it was computer sleep or something else).

I have a corrupted file of about 4GB in size, and I don't want to spend $120 to get it fixed. I sent my file to the people at Treasured (an app/service), and they were able to send me the first 10 seconds of the video with audio and video for free, the rest is $120. So, I know the audio and video is redeemable. It won't play in VLC, Quicktime Player or MPEG Streamclip. I've tried fixing it with a few free tools I downloaded, but they haven't worked.

I've tried using a hex editor and Atom Inspector to fix the "atom length" portions of the Quicktime atoms (it's a .mov file). However, I've hit a roadblock when I find that there are no trak atoms. I'm simply doing a text search for "trak" and nothing shows up.

UPDATE: Turns out that my file is large enough that I'm dealing with a Quicktime file that compressed the data and a "cmov" (compressed movie) atom is there instead of the "trak" etc. I've found a little bit of structure at this link (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTRef_AtomsResources/Content/QTRef_AtomsResources4.html), but I'm still unsure as to what to do exactly.

Anyone know how I can fix this? I'm totally new to this.

Comment: Can you play the file in [VLC](http://videolan.org)?

Comment: No, and I've updated the details above with my new knowledge that the file is compressed, so I won't see the trak atoms, but I have a cmov atom.